# Import Local Jar to Gradle Project in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle

After adding the dependency of a local jar-file in the build.gradle file (see code below) in VSCode I cannot import classes of it (.class-files).

```
dependencies {
  implementation files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
}
```

Every time I try it, I get the following error: "The import net cannot be resolved Java(268435846)"

[image]

With IDEs like IntelliJ, the same import does not cause any problems, so no errors are displayed.

Comment: How do you structure the project? Better to provide more information like file structure etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the local folder in your gradle script:

```
sourceSets.main {
  java {
    srcDir 'dir/to/java/src'
  }
  resources {
    srcDir 'dir/to/resources/'
  }
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir { dirs "libs" }.   // <---- This is what you want
  }
  dependencies {
    jtds name: "jtds-1.3.1.jar". // <--- Name of the dependency
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed the build.gradle, but the import statement shows the exact same error.